# How to send an image using serial port with acoustic modem?

Tags: serial-communication, telecommunication, acoustics

How to convert an image into data bytes to send over series port ? Need to get an image convert the same into data bits which can be transmitter acoustically over channel. i am not sure how to send data serially ? Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the language you are using but most languages will have a library to allow you send data via a serial port.

For example in Java there exists, amongst many other examples: http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/

Comment: Thanks for the upload. I am trying to use C++ or python.

Comment: @JayPatel - for Pythong take a look at, as an example: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial